# Android How to avoid AccessibilityService being killed when user killed the relative application

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I use AccessibilityService to get texts durning user making click-events on other apps.According to official documents,everything goes well.
Method 1 returns true.Method 2 returns true.
I meet the following problem.

The service not works when I kill the relative application manually.And the switcher still is on in system ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS.In this situation.Method 1 returns true.Method 2 returns false.

I turn off the switcher in system ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS and turn on it again,the serivce works and Method 1 Method 2 both return true.

I kill the relative application,turn off and turn on the switcher in system ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS,the service works.

Method 1:

```
private boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context mContext) {
    int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
    // TestService为对应的服务
    final String service = getPackageName() + "/" + MyAccessibilityService.class.getCanonicalName();
    Log.i(TAG, "service:" + service);
    // com.z.buildingaccessibilityservices/android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
    try {
        accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
        Log.v(TAG, "accessibilityEnabled = " + accessibilityEnabled);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

    if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
        Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        // com.z.buildingaccessibilityservices/com.z.buildingaccessibilityservices.TestService
        if (settingValue != null) {
            mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue);
            while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                String accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next();

                Log.v(TAG, "-------------- > accessibilityService :: " + accessibilityService + " " + service);
                if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILITY IS DISABLED***");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static boolean isStartAccessibilityService(Context context, String name){
    AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> serviceInfos = am.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC);
    for (AccessibilityServiceInfo info : serviceInfos) {
        String id = info.getId();
        if (id.contains(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This made user have to turn off and turn on the switcher in settings after he kill the app if he want to use the service.How to solve the problem?

Comment: Kill the relative applications manually? I don't know what you mean by this...

Comment: User kill the application which open service.Not just put the application to the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop this from happening. The Service is part of the package. All processes associated with that package will be killed. Depending on the type of accessibility service, Android may attempt to restart the service itself. There's nothing you can do, and if you do manage to circumvent this, you should report it as a bug, as this would be a pretty significant security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks. I can only write "turn off and turn on the switcher if service not work" in AccessibilityService settings Description.

Comment: @HongZhenHE I'm curious if you ever found a better way to do this.